# Google Scripts - Data Mapping with For Loop Very Slow to Load Data

Tags: performance, for-loop, google-apps-script, data-mapping

I am fairly new to Google Script. I have been translating a guy's code from VBA to write my own database for my properties. The goal is to have the property data stored on a Property Database sheet, and have another 'Summary Sheet' that allows me to view the data for a selected property, edit it, and update it to the database.

I'm using data mapping by putting the cell a1Notation from the Summary Sheet above the corresponding cells in the database sheet. I use a for loop to load the selected property data from the database sheet into the summary sheet, which is executed using onedit when a property is selected. The problem is it is crazy slow. See below. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Thank you!

Image of Summary Sheet:
[image]

Image of Property Database Sheet (Continues to Column 43):
[image]

Definitions:

```
var PropRow, PropCol, PropID
var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
var sheetProp = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Properties');
var sheetPropDB = activeSheet.getSheetByName('PropDB');
```

Loads Property data from Property Database (sheetPropDB) to Summary Sheet (sheetProp). This is the part that is very slow:

```
function Property_Load(){
  sheetProp.activate(); 
  PropRow = sheetProp.getRange('B7').getValue();
  
  for(PropCol = 3; PropCol<43; PropCol++){
    var dataLOC = sheetPropDB.getRange(2,PropCol).getValue(); // gets data mapping cell addresses from PropDB tab 
    var dataVAL = sheetPropDB.getRange(PropRow,PropCol).getValue(); //gets values of cells in PropDB sheet located at the selected properties PropRow and for each PropCol
    var dataPASTE = sheetProp.getRange(dataLOC);  // highlights the cells on the Property tab given by the addresses in dataLOC

    dataPASTE.setValue(dataVAL); // pastes the values from the propDB selected property row into the specified cells of the property tab
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Read [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)  You can probably get a 10X improvement in speed using getValues() instead of getValue() and if you can get all the data at one time and process it as an array that's even better.

Comment: Ok that sounds very doable. If you're feeling friendly and want to save me 3 hours of googling by including a baby example code, that would be awesome. :)

Comment: Best practices has some examples.  And Googling pretty much anyrthing along with the string google apps script will bring up a lot of examples from this site.  Accessing data with getValues() and setValues() is pretty much the norm for most volunteers here at SO  there's literally thousands of answers that can provide a lot of examples.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks. So basically you're saying to feed it directly into each cell...? I understand the getvalues part but I don't understand how you efficiently get each value into its intended cell without a for loop.

Comment: That can be more complicated by your sheet organization.  Obviously programmers tend to want the final result range contiguous and often sheet designers want the data positioned based upon the organization most suitable for the application and the user.  However, you can often compromise by using an intermediate table that allows contiguous loading  and performs the distribution of cells via appropriate formulas. Since the formulas respond to changes in their ranges the intermediate approach is quite useful but depends upon formulas more.  It's up to you.